# How to remove "similar" but not identical content in a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, algorithm, string

Suppose I have this table:

```
ID | description
-------------------
5  | The bird flew over the tree.
2  | The birds, flew over the tree
```

These two rows have "similar" content.  How would I remove #2?

1. What algorithm should I use for "similar" text?
2. How would I do this with Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Alex, how many rows need to be deduped? Hundreds, thousands, millions, etc...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you could try is stripping necessary punctuation and running each sentence through a [stemmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) (e.g. a [Porter Stemmer](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/)).

Once you have a stemmed version of the sentence you could store that in another column for comparison. However, you may find it more space efficient to hash the stemmed sentence if the sentences are long (e.g. over 40 chars on average).

Any rows which share the same stemmed sentence or hash will be highly likely to be equivalent - you could automate their removal, or create a UI to enable a human to rapidly approve each one.

Here's a [Python implementation of the Porter stemmer](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/python.txt).

Comment: Just to have a short "code" for the stemmed sentence to avoid too much overhead. Will modify answer to clarify, thanks for raising it.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, for each value, you'd create a 'simplified' value (remove whatever wasn't essential ... in your example, the punctuation and pluralization), and then compare the simplified values for equality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [LIKE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE description LIKE 'The bird%flew over the tree%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the difference between two strings to be the edit distance, which is the number of operations needed to change one string to another. The set of operations can be anything you want, but if the two strings are of different size in the comparison, you must have an insertion and deletion operation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

I would recommend

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

or

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance

You would then set a threshold of edit distance that indicates the two strings are similar, e.g. 2 edits or 3 edits.

This may not be a good idea if your database is large, though.

In pseudocode, you would basically say

```
if editDist(stringA, stringB) > editThreshold
    remove stringA %or stringB
end
```